# No applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class - renaming column in R

Tags: r, rename

I try to rename 2 of 4 selected columns in data frame `wybory_2005` as you can see below:

```
library(dplyr)

wybory_2005 <- wybory_2005_raw %>%
  select('Powiat', 'Rok', '6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwość', '8 - Platforma Obywatelska') %>%
  rename('Prawo i Sprawiedliwość' = '6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwość','Platforma Obywatelska' = '8 - Platforma Obywatelska')
```

But I receive such error:

> no applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class
> "character"

Edit: I added the commands asked below:

```
>dput(head(wybory_2005_raw))
structure(list(`Nr
okregu` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TERYT = c("020100", 
"020300", "020500", "020600", "020700", "020900"), Powiat = c("boleslawiecki", 
"glogowski", "jaworski", "jeleniogórski", "kamiennogórski", "legnicki"
), `Uprawnieni do glosowania` = c(70154, 71771, 42639, 52884, 
37966, 41918), `Karty wydane (frekwencja)` = c(24559, 27600, 
15079, 18358, 12644, 14565), `Karty wazne (glosy oddane)` = c(24551, 
27582, 15040, 18348, 12642, 14536), `Glosy niewazne` = c(1123, 
1163, 621, 969, 711, 618), `Glosy wazne` = c(23428, 26419, 14419, 
17379, 11931, 13918), `1 - Ruch Patriotyczny` = c(389, 128, 173, 
231, 132, 110), `2 - Polska Partia Pracy` = c(181, 189, 90, 148, 
107, 110), `3 - Liga Polskich Rodzin` = c(1774, 1588, 1091, 1155, 
829, 1119), `4 - Partia Demokratyczna` = c(2137, 1834, 189, 429, 
862, 338), `5 - Socjaldemokracja Polska` = c(585, 965, 443, 1124, 
301, 277), `6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwosc` = c(4985, 7899, 4494, 
3620, 3473, 2730), `7 - Sojusz Lewicy Demokratycznej` = c(3308, 
3720, 1735, 2467, 1830, 1663), `8 - Platforma Obywatelska` = c(5910, 
5562, 2603, 5129, 2202, 2279), `9 - Polska Partia Narodowa` = c(48, 
109, 41, 57, 37, 48), `10 - Polskie Stronnictwo Ludowe` = c(708, 
699, 913, 558, 406, 1641), `11 - Centrum` = c(66, 104, 125, 46, 
42, 45), `12 - Platforma Janusza Korwin-Mikke` = c(466, 411, 
186, 443, 135, 154), `13 - Ogólnopolska Koalicja Obywatelska O.K.O.` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `14 - Polska Konfederacja - Godnosc i Praca` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15 - Samoobrona RP` = c(2562, 3090, 2244, 1856, 
1514, 3318), `16 - Inicjatywa RP` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17 - Dom Ojczysty` = c(267, 
83, 61, 78, 35, 51), `18 - Narodowe Odrodzenie Polski` = c(42, 
38, 31, 38, 26, 35), `19 - Stronnictwo Pracy` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), `19  - Spoleczni Ratownicy` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19  - Mniejszosc Niemiecka` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19 - Mniejszosc Niemiecka Slaska` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Rok = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



  > sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 1250

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zoo_1.8-12      writexl_1.4.2   plm_2.6-3       lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.1    
 [9] tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.4.2   tidyverse_2.0.0 dbplyr_2.3.3    readr_2.1.4     readxl_1.4.2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0  lattice_0.21-8    colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.6.1       generics_0.1.3    htmltools_0.5.5   utf8_1.2.3       
 [8] rlang_1.1.0       pillar_1.9.0      later_1.3.0       glue_1.6.2        withr_2.5.0       DBI_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.3  
[15] munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.3      cellranger_1.1.0  bdsmatrix_1.3-6   miscTools_0.6-28  tzdb_0.3.0        fastmap_1.1.1    
[22] httpuv_1.6.9      lmtest_0.9-40     parallel_4.1.3    fansi_1.0.4       Rcpp_1.0.10       xtable_1.8-4      promises_1.2.0.1 
[29] scales_1.2.1      mime_0.12         maxLik_1.5-2      hms_1.1.3         digest_0.6.31     stringi_1.7.12    collapse_1.9.5   
[36] rbibutils_2.2.13  grid_4.1.3        Rdpack_2.5        cli_3.4.1         tools_4.1.3       sandwich_3.0-2    magrittr_2.0.3   
[43] Formula_1.2-5     pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    MASS_7.3-58.3     timechange_0.2.0  rstudioapi_0.15.0 R6_2.5.1         
[50] nlme_3.1-162      compiler_4.1.3 

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 1250

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zoo_1.8-12      writexl_1.4.2   plm_2.6-3       lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.1    
 [9] tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.4.2   tidyverse_2.0.0 dbplyr_2.3.3    readr_2.1.4     readxl_1.4.2   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0  lattice_0.21-8    colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.6.1       generics_0.1.3    htmltools_0.5.5   utf8_1.2.3       
 [8] rlang_1.1.0       pillar_1.9.0      later_1.3.0       glue_1.6.2        withr_2.5.0       DBI_1.1.3         lifecycle_1.0.3  
[15] munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.3      cellranger_1.1.0  bdsmatrix_1.3-6   miscTools_0.6-28  tzdb_0.3.0        fastmap_1.1.1    
[22] httpuv_1.6.9      lmtest_0.9-40     parallel_4.1.3    fansi_1.0.4       Rcpp_1.0.10       xtable_1.8-4      promises_1.2.0.1 
[29] scales_1.2.1      mime_0.12         maxLik_1.5-2      hms_1.1.3         digest_0.6.31     stringi_1.7.12    collapse_1.9.5   
[36] rbibutils_2.2.13  grid_4.1.3        Rdpack_2.5        cli_3.4.1         tools_4.1.3       sandwich_3.0-2    magrittr_2.0.3   
[43] Formula_1.2-5     pkgconfig_2.0.3   ellipsis_0.3.2    MASS_7.3-58.3     timechange_0.2.0  rstudioapi_0.15.0 R6_2.5.1         
[50] nlme_3.1-162      compiler_4.1.3
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to be [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Backticks (`) are not the same as single quotes (').  It's a typo.  You need backticks.

Comment: @Limey, I don't agree ... `mtcars |> select("cyl") |> rename("cyl2" = "cyl")` works fine, at least with dplyr-1.1.2 (R-4.3.1)

Comment: One of: (1) `select` or `rename` are from a different package, masking the `dplyr::` functions; (2) your data does not inherit `"data.frame"`; or (3) the code here is not perfectly representative of your real code. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(wybory_2005_raw))`, and add the output from `sessionInfo()` into a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans  I stand corrected.  I saw the single quotes and the irregular column names and didn't look further.

Comment: Viktor, your question is close to being closed ... I urge you to provide sample data.

Comment: Sure, give me a second to edit it.

Comment: @r2evans I added the output you asked for. And what does exactly mean to provide sample data? I mean like should I also attached the files where the data is coming from?

Comment: "Sample data" is data that we can play with. It generally should be unambiguous, which can be a problem when somebody shares the _representation_ of an object from the R console; for example, `Sys.time()` presents a string but internally it is really a number with rendering rules; using `dput(...)` gives us the _real number_, which is advantageous at a minimum, required in many situations. Regardless, in the end, "sample data" gives us something to try your code, otherwise the question is just as likely to be closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: BTW, I said `sessionInfo()`, not `sessionInfo(wybo.....)`. When you run into something in R you do not understand, I strongly encourage you to read the help page. In this case, [`?sessionInfo`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html) will tell you that it informs on the versions of R and all packages loaded into the current environment. It is meant to inform my second comment where `select` or `rename` may not be what you think they are.

Comment: When I run your code on your data, I get a different error: `Can't subset columns that don't exist`, because you're trying to rename from `'6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwość'` yet your data has the name `\`6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwosc\`` (no accents). ***This*** is why having a reproducible question matters: we cannot reproduce your error, which means the code you show us is not real enough to your real code, so you've introduced other uncertainties into the process.

Comment: That is also may be the problem. Because, the name in the file is actually '6 - Prawo i Sprawiedliwość' with accents, so maybe the RStudio does not allow to use polish signs?

Comment: (1) R and RStudio are different things. (2) I confess that I'm "blessed" to work in a language largely without accents, so I'm not proficient at dealing with accents, diacritics, "locale", etc. Sorry, I hope somebody else will have a useful suggestion.